# UITableView with transparent background has solid black border

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I tried to set up a transparent background on my `UITableView`, but I have this black border.

[image]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/921192stack.png))</sub>

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[tableView setOpaque:NO];
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to clear the background color.

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Now you can see the background image behind the tableView.